# Java7: Detect all files when creating a new non-empty directory

Tags: java, java-7, watchservice

I'm implementing a WatchDog to look recursively for file changing, deleting and adding in a directory, I'm using linux. The program works well and doing it with Java7 is pretty straightforward, the only thing is that when I add a directory with some files in it I'm not able to monitor the adding of all the contained files. I think the problem is that when I'm adding a new directory, WatchDog has to register it to the WatchService and in the meantime some file added are lost (usually one or two). WatchDog is a Thread that puts every updateEvent in a blockingQueue that is read by another Thread.

Here's th WatchDog: http://pastebin.com/q5SW0iJF

Has anyone experienced the same problem and if yes, how did you solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider the Java 7 [WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview) ? It'll save you reinventing the wheel.

Comment: ? I'm using that, my class is just polling the WatchService for new events. The problem is that the WatchService has to be registered on a directory to look for events on it. If I didn't understand the answer please explain. Thanks